# running sample cropping project in android

Tags: java, android, crop

This must be very stupid question, apologize, but I'm pretty new to things in java.

I downloaded the this image cropping library - https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

It contains two projects. One is the actual library and the other is some sample project.
I imported them both to my workspace and I wish to test this sample project. But the project does not recognize the library's classes.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057931/how-to-zoom-crop-a-image-and-display-the-croped-image-on-imageview/24058159#24058159) on this library. I used this library and it is awsome.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I still didn't manage to run the sample project (which already included this line in the manifest: <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" />). I had to copy the jar file from the bin folder of the library and only then the sample project recognized CropImage.class). I ran it and it failed because it lacked the layout from the library's folder. I copied needed layout, drawables, and styles to the sample project but still it fails on the line that uses the layout 'cropimage.xml' any idea?

Comment: I used ecllipse and only thing that you need to do is to import the project into ecllipse and then add that project to your project as an android library project

Comment: I don't know what was wrong before, but I played with it a little and it works now. Thanks. One quick question, can I use it commercially as it is? can I take the code and embed it inside my commercial project? should I give credit to the owner in some way? (which I'll gladly will, it's a wonderful work to share).

Comment: you have to mention to him that you are using his library by mail and include the apache license in your source thats all I guess