# com.android.camera.action.CROP activity not updating its image

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop

I picked and image from gallery using ACTION_PICK intent and then opened it using com.android.camera.action.CROP intent, it worked fine. But when I overwritten that image file with another image and then opened CROP activity it was still showing previous image(image before overwriting file).

Similar problem occurred with me when I used ACTION_VIEW to preview overwritten image in gallery, the gallery image thumbnail and preview was not updated. So i used

```
File f=new File(getWorkingDirectory() + File.separator +  "temp.jpg");
tempFile=Uri.fromFile(f);    
Intent mediaScanIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
mediaScanIntent.setData(tempFile);
parentClass.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

and this solved the problem for gallery(but not for crop activity).

My question is how should I tell crop activity that image has changed(overwritten completely with a new image), so that when I call again startActivityForResult() for CROP action it displays overwritten image.

Please help me. I am stuck!

Comment: com.android.camera.action.CROP is not a official android intent. It is not guarenteed to work in all circumstances so try some image cropping library

Comment: @IllegalArgument thanks for your suggestion but still I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.android.camera.action.CROP is not official android intent. Apps like gallery and camera support it but there are many devices where this intent is not supported. [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Have a look at [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html) by @commonsware. I have answered cropping image using a library in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057931/how-to-zoom-crop-a-image-and-display-the-croped-image-on-imageview/24058159#24058159).

Comment: Thanks a lot. simple-image-crop-lib works fine. By the way‚ it uses MIT license‚ so do I need to mention it everywhere where I use this library?